# Is it possible to create ERC223 token that is ERC20 backwards compatible

Tags: solidity, contract-design, tokens, erc-20, erc-223

I'm going to use [ERC223](https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard) token, but worry about backward compatibility with [ERC20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md). Here are questions that bother me:

1. Two different Transfer events: 3 args ERC20 `Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)` and 4 args ERC223 `Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value, bytes data)`
2. `transferFrom/approve/allowance` functions and `Approval` event are specified in ERC20 standard, but lacks in ERC223 though it is said that "ERC223 is a superset of the ERC20 token standard".

Could anybody clarify this points for me? I want to avoid situation when token is already deployed and sent to people, but it is not operable at trading exchange and does not not work with services designed for ERC20.

Comment: I am not sure, but events are not part of the standard. Only the functions are.

Comment: ERC223 is compatible with ERC20, and to @Andromelus, events are part of the standard.

Comment: Actually @ElishaDrion, there is a good chance that events might not be apart of that standard. As far as solidity is concerned, due to the natur of how function overriding works, a `Transfer` event function with 3 and 4 arguments are technically 2 totally different functions.

Comment: Perhaps not for ERC223, but it is for ERC20. Check https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md

Comment: @ElishaDrion I know it's standard for ERC20, but was referring to the transfer method through both standards being different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, found ERC20_compatible branch in Dexaran's ERC223 repo https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard/tree/ERC20_compatible and with few additions from master branch implemented fully functional and ERC20 compatible token.

Answer (score 1):

This not about somebody's implementation of the token. ERC223 standard states clearly:

> "ERC223 tokens are backwards compatible with ERC20 tokens. It means
>   that ERC223 supports every ERC20 functional and contracts or services
>   working with ERC20 tokens will work with ERC223 tokens correctly" 
>   https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard

That is, any valid ERC223 implementation is backwards compatible with ERC20